# Web.Config transforms for Multi-Tenant deployment of WebForms app in docker over AWS ECS

Tags: asp.net, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

**Environment**

- ASP.NET WebForms app over IIS
- Docker container host
- AWS ECS hosting platform
- Each client hosting its own copy of the app with private database connection string

**Background**

In the non-docker environment, each copy is a virtual directory under IIS, and thus have their own individual web.config pointing to dedicated databases. The underlying codebase is the same for each client, with no client-specific customization involved. The route becomes / here.

In the docker environment (one container per client), each copy goes over as a central root application.

**Challange**

Since the root image is going to be the same, how to have the web.config overridden for each client deployment.

We shouldn't create multiple images (one per client) as that will mean having extra deployment jobs and losing out on centralization. The connection strings should ideally be stored in some kind of dictionary storage applicable at ECS level which can provide client-specific values upon loading of corresponding containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presenting the approach we used to solve this issue. Hope it may help others struck in similar cases.

With the problem statement tied to having a single root image and having any customization being applied at runtime, we knew that there needs to be a transformation of web.config at time of loading of the corresponding containers.

The solution was to use a PowerShell script that will read the web.config and get replace the *specific* values which were having a custom prefix embedded to the key. The values got passed from custom environmental variables within ECS and the web.config also got updated to have the keys with the prefix added.

Now since the docker container can have only a single entry point, a new base image was created which instantiated an IIS server and called a PowerShell script as startup. The called script called this transformation script and then set the ServiceMonitor on the w3cwp.

Thanks a lot for this article https://anthonychu.ca/post/overriding-web-config-settings-environment-variables-containerized-aspnet-apps/

Answer (score 1):

I would use environment variables as the OP suggests for this with a start up transform, however I want to make the point that you do not want *sensitive* information in ENV variables, like DB passwords, in your ECS task definition.

For that protected information, you should use ECS secrets coupled with Parameter Store in Systems Manager. These values can be stored encrypted in the Parameter Store (using a KMS key) and the ECS Agent will 'inject' them as ENV variables on task startup.

For me, to simplify matters, I simply use secrets for everything although you can choose to only encrypt the sensitive information and leave the others clear.

I dynamically add the secrets for the given application into my task definitions at deploy time by looking up the 'secrets' for the given app by 'namespace' (something that Parameter Store supports). Then, if I need to add a new parameter, I can just add a new secret to the store in the given namespace and re-deploy the app. It will pick up and inject into the task definition any newly defined secrets automatically (or remove ones that have been retired).

Sample ruby code for creating task definition:

```
params = ssm_client.get_parameters_by_path(path: '/production/my_app/').parameters
secrets = params.map{ |p| { name: p.name.split("/")[-1], value_from: p.arn } }
task_def.container_definitions[0].secrets = secrets
```

This last transform injects the secrets such that the secret 'name' is the ENV variable name... which ends up looking like this:

```
      "secrets": [
    {
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:578610029524:parameter/production/my_app/DB_HOSTNAME",
      "name": "DB_HOSTNAME"
    },
    {
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:578610029524:parameter/production/my_app/DB_PASSWORD",
      "name": "DB_PASSWORD"
    }
```

You can see there are no *values* now in the task definition. They are retrieved and injected when ECS starts up your task.

More information:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html

Comment: Note that secrets also supports AWS Secrets Manager, which will also inject an ENV variable, but the value will be a JSON object. Another option, but I preferred the straightforward ENV->VALUE mapping and namespace lookup the Parameter Store provides.

Comment: Adding the key management is the next level we are targeting, so that's definitely in our roadmap :)